# How do I resolve a issue related to IAR Embedded Workbench ARM library header file for successfully running PC-Lint in IAR?

Tags: iar, pc-lint

When I run PC-Lint on my code on IAR Workbench it conflicts with a code snippet present in library header file `yvals.h` which I am including below and then PC-Lint stops working.

```
/* IAR compiler version check */
#if (__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__ < 9) || (__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__ > 9)
  #error "DLib compiled with wrong (version of IAR) compiler"
#endif
```

The version of IAR compiler that I am using is `co-iar.lnt`. I chose this compiler version from PC-Lint config file.

Answer (score 0):

The IAR compiler internally defines various preprocessor symbols (like `__IAR_SYTEMS_ICC`) which are not known by PC-Lint in your setup. Fortunately you can instruct the IAR compiler to generate a file with all theses symbols using the command line option `--predef_macros iar_symbols.h`. You can add this option in any Embedded Workbench project under `Project > Options > Compiler > Extra Options`. Once you compile your project the file `iar_symbols.h` is generated. Afterwards you can remove the `--predef_macros` option from your project again.

Now you need to instruct PC-Lint to read the generated file by adding the option `-header(iar_symbols.h)` to your PC-Lint command line. This should resolve your issue.

Note that the list of pre-defined symbols depends on the compiler version used. If you use different IAR compiler versions for different projects you should generate one `iar_symbols.h` header for each compiler version.